# AWS EC2 ssh can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

While creating an EC2 instance, let AWS create the key, download to local Mac, then `chmod 400 my-key.pem`.
At the local terminal:

```js
ssh -i "my-key.pem" ubuntu@<public DNS>
The authenticity of host '<public DNS> (<public ip>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:GO...4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '<public DNS>,<public ip>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ssh_packet_read: Connection closed

$ssh -i "my-key.pem" ubuntu@<public DNS>
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64)
...
ubuntu@ip-<private ip>:~$ls
ubuntu@ip-<private ip>:~$
```

I am confused as to what has happened. First why the authenticity of host could not be established, after all I got this key from AWS when creating another instance and used the same key to connect to this instance which when this instance was created, it was given the same key pair name.

When answering 'yes' to the question, what exactly did it do?
after all the key is chmod to 400, so no write access.
What is the high level description of what went on between the local machine ssh and AWS?
Thanks

Comment: The `authenticity of host X` message just indicates that the SSH client couldn't verify that the server you're connecting to is the one you intended to connect to. When you tell it yes, you're authenticating the server, so the host key is cached. When you connect again, the host key is looked up in the cache (resulting in a hit), so it doesn't need to ask you again.

Comment: @millinon OK. Just another question. why `ls` did not produce any output?

Comment: maybe the folder was empty?

Comment: @BretzL ubuntu root is expected to have `boot, lib64, opt, run,...` or I am missing something?

Comment: You are doing `ls` in /home/ubuntu. cd to / and do `ls`. The reason you are not seeing any file in `/home/ubuntu` could be there are only files that start with a period. Try `ls -a`.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace ubuntu with onetick in:**

ssh -i "keyfile.pem" ubuntu@[public DNS]

**to**

ssh -i "keyfile.pem" onetick@[public DNS]